# How do I figure out what all the request headers in my request object are?

Tags: ruby, get, request, http-headers, net-http

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I have a request I set up like so:

```
2.3.0 :001 > url = 'http://www.mydomeina.com/results/browse.cfm?ID=4187141102&Gen=B&Begin=1&End=31&Max=31'
 => "http://www.mydomeina.com/results/browse.cfm?ID=4187141102&Gen=B&Begin=1&End=31&Max=31" 
2.3.0 :002 > uri = URI(url)
 => #<URI::HTTP http://www.mydomeina.com/results/browse.cfm?ID=4187141102&Gen=B&Begin=1&End=31&Max=31> 
2.3.0 :003 > req = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
 => #<Net::HTTP::Get GET> 
2.3.0 :004 > req["Referer"] = 'http://www.mydomeina.com/results/browse.cfm?ID=4187141102&Gen=B&Begin=1&End=31&Max=31'
 => "http://www.mydomeina.com/results/browse.cfm?ID=4187141102&Gen=B&Begin=1&End=31&Max=31"
```

I set `req["Referer"]` as an example of setting a header.  There may be other headers in my request object.  How do I figure out what they all are?  This fails:

```
2.3.0 :009 >   req.keys
NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for #<Net::HTTP::Get GET>
Did you mean?  key?
```

as does `req.headers`.  How can I iterate over my request object to figure out what all the headers are?  It is not an option to construct the request object in a different way then what I am doing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
 req.each_key{|k| puts k}
```

or

```
 req.each{|k,v| puts "#{k} => #{v}"}
```

to see methods on an object from inside console you can always do

```
req.methods - Ojbect.methods
```